# How to do correct setting of the Uboot to run a baremetal program on an embeded system

Tags: arm, embedded, bare-metal, soc

I had a cycloneVsoc board and I debugged the baremetal program I wrote, the project is based on the makefile and I tranfer the axf file to the bin file.

According to the guide of the Intel AN709, I need a correctly set SPL(first stage of Uboot) and using mkimage tool to change the bin file to a bin file with some special heads.

My plan is to put the spl and the bin with special head to the sdcard and let the board start from there.

I created an area called A2(dont know why, I may related to "SPL/TPL-> Partition Type on the MMC to load U-boot from" SECTION setting in Uboot menuconfig) as num = 2, and put the "u-boot-with-spl.sfp"(not the u-boot-spl.sfp in the spl file, but I dont know the difference). The section is 10M large.

And I created a FAT32 with 1024M size as num=1, I want to put the bin file into it and read/change the area through the windows host by a SD card reader.

In SPL, since I used the newest version of the SOCEDS, the BSP-editor settings didnt do anything any more. So I have to set the Uboot myself. I enable the FAT and SD/EMMC option and decide not to touch other settings.

For the bin file, I intend to use the mkimage to add the special head but I dont know two settings:
-c the start address and -e the entry address. -c seems to be the physical address of the SD card and -e is -c address + 0x40(correct me if Im wrong).

So my questions are:

1. How to set the SPL so that when it done it can find/load the bin file in the FAT32 area?
2. How to get the correct address for the mkimage?
3. Can spl choose which bin file is to loaded, if yes, how?

Thank you for your time and willing to help,
please do have a nice day :)

Yours sincerely

Alex C

Comment: this is not an arm question arm has nothing to do with this, sdcard booting, etc are software plus chip.  (arm doesnt make chips).  so what chip, what do the chip docs say and what does the code show, etc..